# getting a string of errors that are mostly "cannot find symbols" and is taking too ling to run

Tags: java, performance

I'm new at java and I'm getting a string of errors and is taking forever to run.  Im making a code that could segregate even and odd numbers and returning them together. the errors are mostly "cannot find symbol"s and could someone please help me with the performance please?

My code:

```
public int operate(int[]array){
    int odd;
    int even;
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        int x = ar[i];
        if(x % 2 == 0){
            // if the number is even...
            even++;
        }
        else{
            ///if the number is odd...
            odd++;
        }
    }
    int[] evenarr = even;
    int[] oddarr = odd;
    int[] returnarr = odd + even;
    int evenindex = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        int x = ar[i];
        if(x % 2 == 0){
            // if the number is even...
            evenarr[evenindex] = x;
            evenindex++;
        }
        else{
            ///if the number is odd...
            oddarr[oddindex] = x;
            oddindex++;
        }
    }
    evenarr + oddarr = returnarr;

}
```

The error:

```
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
         ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ar
  location: class Main
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    int x = ar[i];
            ^
  symbol:   variable ar
  location: class Main
Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    int x = ar[i];
               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:33: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
    int[] evenarr = even;
                    ^
Main.java:34: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
    int[] oddarr = odd;
                   ^
Main.java:35: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
    int[] returnarr = odd + even;
                          ^
Main.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
         ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ar
  location: class Main
Main.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)
                               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    int x = ar[i];
            ^
  symbol:   variable ar
  location: class Main
Main.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    int x = ar[i];
               ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main
Main.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        oddarr[oddindex] = x;
               ^
  symbol:   variable oddindex
  location: class Main
Main.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        oddindex++;
        ^
  symbol:   variable oddindex
  location: class Main
Main.java:53: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
    evenarr + oddarr = returnarr;
            ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int[]
Main.java:54: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
    return(returnarr);
           ^
19 errors
```

I am expecting the result to be an integer array with [even, odd]

Comment: Try `for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {`

Comment: The errors show you where the problems are by indicating with a ^

Comment: Start by fixing the first one, and recompile. You'll find that some of the later ones will be fixed automatically.

Comment: The error message clearly says, variable i is not found, so declare i. Cannot convert int to int[].

Comment: You have not initialized various variables like `ì` , `ar` , `oddindex`, etc. Try reading the error message.

Comment: You can't be having a performance problem because the code isn't even compiling. So if it looks like it's taking a long time, it's probably because it's not actually running at all.

Comment: You can't convert an int to an int[]. So the following won't work: `int[] evenarr = even; int[] oddarr = odd; int[] returnarr = odd + even;`

Comment: Plus what is `ar`? I suspect you mean `array` from the parameter passed to the method.

Comment: You can simplify code if you use List<Integer> instead of arrays. Then you don't need to loop through the array twice.

Comment: The error messages are there for a reason! They are telling you what's or what could be wrong in your code. In this case it exactly tells you what's wrong!!! Please read the error messages carefully, and don't post questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All the `cannot find symbol` errors are because you did not declare the variables before using them

`for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)` needs to be changed to `for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++)` for it to work.

2. `int[] evenarr = even;` - This assignment is illegal.
   I am assuming what you are trying to do here is to create an array with the size of the number of even numbers in the list.
   You probably would want to do this - `int[] evenarr = new int[even]`
3. You cannot merge two arrays by doing `array3 = array1 + array2`

Try this instead -

`int[] result = new int[evenarr.length + oddarr.length];
System.arraycopy(evenarr, 0, result, 0, evenarr.length);
System.arraycopy(oddarr, 0, result, evenarr.length, oddarr.length);`

On a side note - you do not need to parse the array to find the sizes of even and odd numbers. You may use a list instead which dynamically grows (See [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html))

Comment: Thank you VERY much.   I have just started with programming back then! :)

Answer (score 0):

More Java like and using lists, you can simplify it like so:

```
List<Integer> simplified(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int n : array) {
        if (n%2 == 0) {
            even.add(n);
        } else {
            odd.add(n);
        }
    }
    even.addAll(odd);
    return even;
```

}